# Debugging Dylibs from Delphi XEx (XE4)

Tags: delphi, debugging, dylib

Is it possible to debug Dylibs from Delphi, or is this functionality not included?

As I understand it, I should be able to:

1) Create a Host Application which loads up the Dylib that is deployed by Delphi

2) Set the "Host Application" in "Run -> Parameters..." to match this new application.

3) When firing up the debugger in Delphi, it should start the Host Application. The Host Application loads up the Delphi-generated Dylib. I should be able to hook onto an entry point from my Windows machine, and trace through the code.

Just like it works on Windows, but on a remote machine.

Unfortunately, Delphi does not seem to catch the execution of the Dylib at all.  It **is** being loaded (and I've even gone out of my way to look through my entire machine to see if there were any other identically named Dylibs getting loaded by mistake), but Delphi takes no notice of the Dylib getting executed by the Host Process, and just waits for the Host to end.

Any solutions?

Comment: I've been fighting with this for hours, and I just realized that Delphi is failing at deploying an "rsm" file, due to a file naming error.  This is important for debugging, probably.  Still not sure if that's the root cause, or why Delphi botched the filename.  Just to check it, I started a fresh Delphi project - same error.

Comment: I managed to deploy the .rsm file - Didn't help at all.

Comment: Perhaps the improved [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Attach_to_Process) with XE5 will help.

Comment: I wish it did.  When I try to attach to a process on the Remote machine, my application is not displayed.  I can't even track it down by the PID delphi provides.  This is with the "show system processes" button checked as well, so I should be seeing everything.

Comment: Is the remote debug server running, as it says in the "Remote machine" portion of that documentation? (I don't develop for OSX/iOS, but there are several steps you have to take to set them up that have to be followed closely. I'd presume that XE4 uses the "old style debugging" referred to in that section.)

Comment: I'll keep putting up info as I work on it, and I'll try your suggestion.  From what I can tell: Delphi is already attaching to the correct process (delphi stays in "debug" mode until I close the application on my OSX machine), but it cannot seem to latch on to any of the breakpoints I've set in my IDE, while the Dylib is running.

Comment: The main issue IMO - debugging with an OSX application "just works", and I'm seeing in the Event Log - "Module Load: Project1. Has Debug Info ..."  But with a .dylib project, it says "No Debug Info".  Seems like this is the first place I would look.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the Delphi IDE doesn't appear to keep track of which libraries are loaded up by the Host Process.  This would make it impossible to debug anything but an application.  I have doubts that EMB has tested this at all.

Comment: I have doubts about the veracity of that statement, especially since they have documented steps to debug Dylibs. It seems much more likely that you're missing something along the way, but of course it's much easier to blame the tool than the carpenter. :-)

Comment: Is that documentation specific to Dylibs though?  I have no doubts that it applies to .dll's just fine.  Anyways, I _hope_ that it's me at fault here.

Comment: Yes. :-) Did you see [this page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Release_Notes_for_XE4#Ensure_Debug_Info_for_Run-Time_Packages:_Add_.dcp_Files_to_Deployment)? Run-time packages includes Dylibs for OS X. Are you deploying the .dcp file for your Dylib as well so that debugging symbols are available? (If not, that would explain your "No Debug Info". :-)

Comment: OMFG - the answer is in the release notes?  I will try this out.  I know it's important to RTFM, but I never thought of release notes.

Comment: I'm not so sure.  That release note is specific to a different situation (a delphi-specific library being loaded by a delphi application, not a delphi generated dylib).  Also, I've found that the "no debug info" issue I mentioned earlier is in reference to the executable that starts the process - not the dylib that gets loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I recently realized that XE4 can debug dylibs on Snow Leopard.  So, load up an old version of OSX, if you've got one lying around.

Ok, here's the solution:

1) Switch over to Delphi XE5

1a) Wait for bitterness over upgrade price to subside.  This may take a while.  Consider waiting for XE6 to come out first.

2) XE5 Does track which libraries are loaded by an executable process, but it still fails to deploy the debugging symbols properly.

You will have to change a filename in your OSX output directory.  This directory is located at "yourProjectFolder/OSX32/Debug".  Build your project, and then rename "yourProject.rsm" to "yourProject.dylib.rsm".  This is the name which Delphi is trying to deploy already, so you will not have to add the file to your Deployment Settings.

I'm hoping that there's a way to automate the renaming of this file (maybe the .dproj file can be hacked).  If I can find one, I'll add it to this answer.

3) Goto 1a

Comment: I've been using XE2 and not been able to get debugging to work. However I also have XE5 installed so will try with that (project is not easily upgraded though). For deployment problem you should be able to set output path by editing the dproj file with text editor (search for "<Deployment>").

Comment: Editing the dproj file didn't help so I worked around the rsm deployment problem by adding a post build event (Project Options - Build events) like this: copy "$(PROJECTDIR)\libMyVstPlugin.rsm" "$(PROJECTDIR)\libMyVstPlugin.dylib.rsm" /Y

Comment: Thanks Ville!  I'll add this to the main answer when I get a chance to test it out.

Comment: I'm having this other annoying problem now. If the debugger stops on a breakpoint in a dylib and then later I want to continue execution (using F9 or F4) I get "Debug process is already running". So I have to restart the debugger to set another breakpoint. This happens to you too?

Comment: I haven't done much testing just yet.  Still, are you running XE5 Update 2?  Maybe it has been fixed in an update.  Although it was buggy for me (it's buggy even with programs instead of .dylibs), I do remember being able to resume execution (F9)!

Comment: After fighting with this a bit more, I've found that there is a whole different range of bugs when attempting to use XE5.  The truth of the matter is that Delphi is a complete mess these days.  The solution to this problem is to never even consider using it.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about the bugs you've encountered? I had a few initial problems with XE5 but now development for OSX runs quite smoothly.

Comment: I'm using FMX.  Creating an FMX Form from a DLL fails on Windows.  I didn't have this issue with XE4.  Also, loading the DLL in debug mode fails 50% of the time in Windows, causing me to close BDS from the taskbar and restart.  So at this point, I'm not even concerned about the OSX end of it.  It's just too time consuming to figure all of this out.